# Live stream encoder in .NET RTSP, RTMP

Tags: .net, live-streaming, encoder

I am wondering if anyone knows of any live stream encoders that we can our in our .NET application. We are currently using StreamCoders but they do not have all the functionality we need e.g. Closed Captions.

The software should be able to encoder our live stream (*preferably H264*) and send that out to a URL VIA RTSP and RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is execute FFmpeg as a child process.  It supports everything you need.

Alternatively, you can link to libffmpeg.